# OpenGL with PhoneGap

Tags: mobile, opengl-es, cordova, opengl-es-2.0

Is it possible to use hardware accelerated graphics with **OpenGL ES** (preferably 2.0) when developing with **PhoneGap**?

If yes, are there any resources to get started, preferably with source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not yet but an active prototyping project is underway for Android and its very promising. As soon as we have a measurable amount of tests passing the code will seeing the light of day. Likely, this fall.

Comment: Thank you, Brian, really looking forward to it. Is it going to be part of the regular distribution? I would appreciate if you updated the answer once it is released.